# Determine Sample Size

Tags: statistics

I have the following example problem:

```
 You really want to use a sample size such that about 95% of the average 
fall within +/- 5 minutes of the mean 6.78 hours.

Using the calculated standard deviation in part ( b) determine the number of 
students, you need?
```

My calculated standard deviation is 0.041hours the original was 1.24 hours

I used the following question

n= ((z*)( σ)/m)^2

and used a z* if 1.96 and m of .08 but I get a sample size of only 1 when the correct answer is 886?

What am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "my calculated standard deviation," but here is how to do it:
you want a $95\%$ confidence interval to be within $5$ minutes. As you have noted, a $95\%$ confidence interval corresponds to approximately $1.96$ standard deviations from the mean (you call this $z^*$), and you want this to be $5$ minutes. Therefore a single standard deviation should be about $5/1.96 \approx 2.55$ minutes.

Now we know that the standard deviation of the sample means scales with the inverse square root of sample size, i.e. $\sigma_\mu = \sigma_{population}/\sqrt{n}$. In particular, $n = (\sigma_{population}/\sigma_\mu)^2$. Using $\sigma_{population} \approx 74.4 \text{ minutes}$, and $\sigma_\mu = 2.55 \text{ minutes}$, we get the desired answer of $n \approx 886$.

Comment: In part (b) of the example question, we were supposed to calculate the standard deviation which I got to be .041 hours which is the standard deviation that needs to be used in this problem

Comment: You have to use the population standard deviation in this problem. In a previous problem, I'm guessing they gave you a sample size and asked you to calculate the standard deviation of the sample means?

Comment: Correct. But I see I how to work the problem now based on your explanation. Thank you.